# How to move image up and down from a fixed location, rather than starting from the bottom?

Tags: android, android-animation, translate-animation

The code I am currently using:

```
    TranslateAnimation mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f);
    mAnimation.setDuration(2000);
    mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
    mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    imageView.setAnimation(mAnimation);
```

Here is the [result.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1hArV-ExodqcVFPaVg2U0ZNNmc/view?usp=sharing) (ignore the image quality, I will change it).

I had placed the image in the horizontal center, vertically in line with the floating action button. I want it to start from there.

Also, optionally, I created a fade in-fade out `AlphaAnimation`. How do I synchronize them both?

**Code for AlphaAnimation:**

```
AlphaAnimation blinkAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // Change alpha from fully visible to invisible
    blinkAnimation.setDuration(1000); // duration - half a second
    blinkAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); // do not alter animation rate
    blinkAnimation.setRepeatCount(5000); // Repeat animation infinitely
    blinkAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
TranslateAnimation mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f);
//Less up :     TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -0.5f);
```

To combine with alphaAnimation :

```
AlphaAnimation blinkAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // Change alpha from fully visible to invisible
    blinkAnimation.setDuration(1000); // duration - half a second
    blinkAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); // do not alter animation rate
    blinkAnimation.setRepeatCount(5000); // Repeat animation infinitely
    blinkAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
set.addAnimation(trAnimation);
set.addAnimation(mAnimation);
imageView.startAnimation(set)
```

Comment: Thanks, this does help, but the image now goes a little too high up, how to stop it before? Or if you could explain the parameters on `TranslateAnimation`, I can try myself.

Comment: If you want to stop before, change   TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f); to   TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -.0.5f);

Answer (score 3):

Here is detail code for Fade-In|Fade-Out and also for Move-Up|Move-Down

**Move-up and Move-Down Image View code:**

```
    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f); // this is distance of top and bottom form current positiong

           anim.setDuration(2000);
           anim.setRepeatCount(3);
           anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);  
           downloadIV.startAnimation(anim);
```

**Fade-In and Fade-Out:**

```
   AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.setRepeatCount(4);
    anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

    //anim.setFillAfter(true);
   downloadIV.startAnimation(anim);
```